# Escape double quotes in -replace

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script to replace DEV web config entries with QA values.

So far good, but now I have some values with double quotes:

```
   (Get-Content $targetFile) |
         Foreach-Object {              
            $_ -replace "<add key="Path" value="/DEV/Reports" />", "<add key="WebReportsPath" value="/QA/Reports" />" `
                -replace "<add key="EmpReport" value="/DEV/Emp/Reports" />", "<add key="EmpReport" value="/QA/Emp/Reports" />" `                                        
                -replace "olddatabase", "newdatabase"

         } |
         Set-Content $targetFile
```

I get parser error when I run. If I change double quote to single quote like

```
`-replace 'valwithdoublequote' 'valwithdoublequote' still I get parser error. How to escape this?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `-replace` is using regex, you should use `[regex]::Escape` to escape your characters (or use `$_.Replace()` instead):

```
(Get-Content $targetFile) |
         Foreach-Object {              
            $_ -replace [regex]::Escape('<add key="Path" value="/DEV/Reports" />'), '<add key="WebReportsPath" value="/QA/Reports" />' `
                -replace [regex]::Escape('<add key="EmpReport" value="/DEV/Emp/Reports" />'), '<add key="EmpReport" value="/QA/Emp/Reports" />' `                                        
                -replace "olddatabase", "newdatabase"

         } |
         Set-Content $targetFile
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. But I have a for loop since we have QA1 to QA 4. is it possible to replace count ? `-replace [regex]::Escape('<add key="Path" value="/DEV/Reports" />'), '<add key="WebReportsPath" value="/QA"+$i+"/Reports" />' `. I get bad replacement arguement

Comment: since you are using single quotes, you have to also use a format string like `replace [regex]::Escape('<add key="Path" value="/DEV/Reports" />'), ('<add key="WebReportsPath" value="/QA{0}/Reports" />' -f $i)`